# Can I limit generic type argument to be one of 2 unrelated classes?

Tags: scala, generics

I'd like to be able to do something like this (won't actually work):

```
class A[T <: B | C]
```

... and expect this to be valid:

```
new A[B]
new A[C]
```

... and this to yield compiller error:

```
new A[D]
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use implicits:

```
trait AArg[T]

class A[T](implicit e: AArg[T])

implicit val argB = new AArg[B] { }
implicit val argC = new AArg[C] { }
```

although this doesn't prevent someone from creating an implicit val of type `AArg[D]`.

Comment: Actually you *can* prevent it by making the trait `sealed`, assuming that is desirable in the application's context.

Comment: would be worth mentioning AArg is a type class.